# How do fighters detect laser locking?

Tags: missile-lock

I've been wondering this for a while. I understand how planes detect electromagnetic waves with it's radar but I don't get how they detect if missile has locked to the plane using laser. Only ways I can figure are some kind of tiny receptors all around the plane but it sounds very impractical way.

Comment: "Receptors all around the plane" is pretty much how regular radar warning systems work.

Comment: When someone shoot laser to your mouth you can still see the flash of laser. You don't need to put detectors everywhere, but only a few to detect scatters and diffraction. However, you might be right: a laser warning system won't work well for low-power beams unless the whole vehicle is covered by sensors (` Most laser warning systems produced so far can not detect laser beam-riding missiles because of their weak emissions which have signals less than 1% of laser range finder power. ` https://dspace.lib.cranfield.ac.uk/handle/1826/1047)

Comment: @user3528438 Please post answers in answers, not in comments.

Comment: Unless you can provide more details, I think, in the system you are after, the laser beam is delivered by a [designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_designator) (airborne or on the ground) but not from the missile itself. The beam is not a cylinder, it diverges by some angle (e.g. 10 milliradians). Therefore at a certain distance the beam diameter is several meters and only 3 or 4 sensors are necessary to detect it from any direction.

Comment: Which weapon includes laser guiding?

Comment: They have a number of cats positioned around the aircraft, best laser detection known.